# Google Play Store access invitation with office domain ID

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Google play store invitation with Microsoft outlook mail id. Trying to accept the invitation, it redirected to the Google login account page. But office not to use personal mail id,  how can I access to Google play developer account? I would appreciate any idea about it?

I couldn't get any solution. No help from Google also. Suggest any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Google account with your custom email address, like `a@abc.com`:

1. Press the invitation link.
2. Press Create Account.
3. On the Create your Google Account screen press "Use my current email address instead".
4. Create the account and you're good to go.

[image: Create Google account with custom email address]

Answer (score 0):

Additional users on the Google Play Console need to use a Google (Gmail or Google Apps) account.

- create a Gmail account
- get the account owner to re-send the invitation to the Gmail account